# Store console's output to a variable on each line

Tags: python, python-3.x, stdout, sys

I have a function that prints some output, I want to store the console output line-by-line and send it to the user in real-time (until the word **Downloaded** from `sys.stdout.write("Downloaded")` printed on console).
I've done the following but don't know why it gaves me error and if there's a better way:

```py
for line in sys.stdout.readlines():
    MyMessage.edit(line)
        # just to mention that I've tried both readlines and splitlines.
        if sys.stdout.read().splitlines() == 'Downloaded':
            break
```

The error:

```py
for line in stdout.read().splitlines():
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable
```

Comment: @EliHarold like this: `mysysout = sys.stdout.readlines()
    for line in mysysout:`? same error.

Comment: yeah changed that too but nothing changed. don't know what's the problem.

Comment: your error says `for line in stdout.read().splitlines():` but your code does not include this, please paste the code that actually gives the error, and the error that it gives.

Comment: Since the error says `for line in stdout.read().splitlines():` but the code doesn't match it is hard to help. `for line in stdout.read().splitlines():` should probably be `for line in sys.stdout.read().splitlines():` like your code in the question.

Comment: I've actually imported the `stdout` from `sys`, though used `sys.stdout` too, the output is not empty either..

Comment: so if you print `sys.stdout.readlines()` it isn't empty?

Comment: That should still give an error...

Comment: Either way, I think you should use `subprocess`, check [this](https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2013/10/11/catching-string-from-stdout-with-python/).

Comment: yeah that gives the same error too! thanks for the subprcoess solution, I'll do that if there are no direct ways to do this :(